# EMF setter method doesn't check equality of two objects

Tags: eclipse-plugin, setter, eclipse-emf, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I have generated code using EMF. The setter looks as following:

`public void setContent(String newContent) {
        String oldContent = content;
        content = newContent;
        if (eNotificationRequired())
            eNotify(new ENotificationImpl(this, Notification.SET,...);
    }`

I have a eclipse dialog for editing the content associated with this model code. Now, whenever the user click `ok` on dialog the content is set and the editor becomes dirty. (As model is changed)

Even if the user doesn't change anything in the dialog and just presses `ok` the editor becomes dirty as this `setter method` has no way to check if the two Strings (for that matter -  any two objects) are same. How can we achieve that editor doesn't get dirty in case of no changes.

Comment: What is the condition of becoming dirty? Is it a command stack change or a notification? Need more code here.

Comment: @MrCovex: The condition for becoming dirty is command stack change. If anything changes in model, the editor becomes dirty.

Comment: Then you should prevent sending commands, that don't really change the model, to the stack. EcoreUtil.equals(org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject, org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject) may help. Without the code, cannot give a more detailed answer.

Comment: @MrCovex: Thanks EcoreUtil.equals did the job! Is there any way to generate the equals method automatically during code generation?

Comment: Javadoc says that the framework assumes that implementations will not specialize #equals(Object) (nor #hashCode()) http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.5.0/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/EObject.html